# How can I limit an entity reference selection to a specific field value on the reference

Tags: entities, 9

I have a content type `Research` which has a an entity reference type of `People`.

The problem is that I don't want to show ALL people but only people which have a certain value under their field named `type`.
I was trying to find it here:
[image]
Anyone an idea how to only show a content-type for a certain field value of that content type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an Entity Reference display in a view and use that to generate the available options.

1. In your view of choice, create a new display of type *Entity Reference* and configure it so that it only shows the content you want.
2. Navigate back to your field configuration screen (the one in your screenshot) and change *Reference Method* from "Default" to "Views: Filter by an entity reference view" and choose the display you created in step 1.